# Javascript Validation Not Working When Submitting

Tags: javascript, html

I've been developing my first website, and I'm having issues with a javascript validation script. My code:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Territory</title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <script type="text/javascript"> //Main Javascript function giving me issues
    function validate(form)
    {
      fail = validateTerrNum(document.checkOut.numberOut.value);
      fail += validateFirstName(document.checkOut.fName.value);
      fail += validateLastName(document.checkOut.lName.value);
      if (fail == "") 
    return true;
      else 
      {
        alert(fail);
        return false;
      }
    }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript>
        function validateTerrNumber(field)
        {
     if (field == "") return "No territory number was entered. \n";
     else if (field.length > 3)
    return "Territory numbers must be less than four characters. \n";
    else if (/[^0-9]/.test(field))
        return "Only 0-9 allowed in territory number. \n";
    return "";
        }

        //Note: Does not sanitize string
        function validateFirstName(field)
        {
     if (field == "") return "No first name was entered. \n";
     return "";
        }

        //Again, note that this function does not sanitize string
        function validateLastName(field)
        {
     if (field == "") return "Not last name was entered. \n";
     return "";
        }
        </script>

        <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
     <th colspan="2" align="center">Check Out</th>
      <form name="checkOut" method="post" onSubmit="validate(this)"> 
    <tr><td>Territory Number</td><td><input type="text" name="numberOut"     tabindex="1" maxlength="3" size="3" /></td>
                    </tr><tr><td>First Name of Holder</td><td><input type="text" name="fName" tabindex="2" maxlength="15"/></td>
                    </tr><tr><td>Last Name of Holder</td><td><input type="text" name="lName" tabindex="3" maxlength="15" /></td>
                    </tr><tr><td><input type ="checkbox" name="specialC" tabindex="4" value="Yes"/> Special Campaign</td>
                    </tr><tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Check Out" /></td>
                </form>
            </table>
</body>
</html>
```

It is obviously poorly formatted - result of copy and paste. To be more specific, this issue is with the javascript validation. When I hit "Check Out," the validation does not prevent it when I put in bad values. The script is quite simple, but for some reason I can't figure out what is going on with it (I'm fairly new to javascript).

I know the issue is not my browser as I have many javascripts running throughout it. The only thing I can think of is that the form does not have a method. It will be another validation, but written in php - the javascript is really just a prevalidation for the client.

Any help would be appreciated.

-Mlagma

Comment: Why don't you try to make your "submit" a button and call your java script from the button. If validation passes just call form.submit();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the submit going ahead after validation fails you need:

```
onSubmit="return validate(this)"
```

instead of your current code:

```
onSubmit="validate(this)"
```

Your `validate()` function already returns `true` or `false`, but those values were not being returned from the event handler itself. If you think of the code between the quotes of `onSubmit=""` as the body of a function this makes sense.

And, asTeemu pointed out, your `validate()` function tries to invoke a function called `validateTerrNum` when actually you've declared that function as `validateTerrNumber`.

With these problems corrected you can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/Wvcy3/

Comment: You prevented me from an issue I haven't even encountered yet, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have this line in `validate()`:

```
fail = validateTerrNum(document.checkOut.numberOut.value);
```

And there is this function:

```
function validateTerrNumber(field){...
```

Also `document.checkOut` is `undefined` rather than `form` element (browser dependent???), it's better to use `document.getElementById('numberOut').value` instead, (same for `fName` and `lName`). Ofcourse you'll need to add these `id`s in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback; that immediately fixed the issue. I can't believe I completely missed that.

Comment: I definitely prefer `document.getElementById()`, but `document.checkOut` worked fine in the demo I included with my answer. (And if you want to use `getElementById()` you should give the elements ids...)